# Images printing (on paper) differently on various browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I am trying to print out an ID card from a web page. It's important that the card print out to an exact physical size on the paper, which for our purposes here can be 3 inches wide by 2 inches tall.

Each card is an image in a `<div>` element and here's what I think is the relevant CSS:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        margin: 0.5in;
    }
    .card__print {
        width: 3in;
        height: 2in;
    }
    .card__print img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

When I print the card on Safari, it is about the right height (2in), but slightly too wide (~3.25in), which means the card is actually being stretched.

When I print on Firefox or Chrome, the card seems to have the correct aspect ratio, but it's slightly too narrow and too short. Both printouts are exactly the same as one another, however.

All three browsers are set to 100% scale.

Is there a way to fix this issue, or do the various browsers simply interpret the page differently?

Comment: Did you try using [CSS media queries for print](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/CSS_for_print_tutorial)? That might help eliminate the inconsistencies across browsers.

Comment: Yes, I am, but I should have said so. I've edited my answer.